# Is there any way in slack api to add interactive buttons without a slack app

Tags: slack-api, slack

I'm new to the slack api. I was thinking about posting an interactive message to my team channel via an incoming webhook. But the docs say that for an incoming message to work, it requires an app to be created with Interactive messages enabled. Is there any workaround to make it happen without the app?

Comment: Don't think so. Where would the interactions go without an app?

Comment: I just wanted to know whether there a possibility of adding it like a custom integration, outside the app

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible, [you need an app](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons) (this does not mean you'd have to make your app public, mind you)

> Posting messages with buttons requires registering a Slack app.
>   Interactive messages cannot be posted using a custom integration.

Comment: How do you not make it public? I have no interest in posting to the directory, but it seems that this is the only route for our team to use this app functionality. Am I missing something?

Comment: There are two steps. Step 1 is creating an app, configuring it, etc. Step 2 is filling out the form required to publish it in the app directory. Your app is operational at Step 1 and your team can install it. You don't have to publish it at all

Comment: Right - I've been stuck at Step 1, as I have created the app and have configured it, but I can't seem to install it into my team. Glad to know that I don't have to do Step 2 for my team to install it. I'm just having an issue with installing it (despite completing step 1).

Comment: Does your app use an "add to slack" button? check this [documentation](https://api.slack.com/slack-apps#slack-button). This would just like an app you'd share with other teams, except that you will not share it. Alternatively, you can generate a token for your team in your dashboard, and add that token as an environment variable to your app.